# Azure DevOps Api error: RuleValidationException: The field 'State' contains the value 'Active' that is not in the list of supported values C#

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, azure-devops

I try to create Azure DevOps workitems programmatically in C#, but when I add the field `System.State` with value `"Active"` I get an error:

> RuleValidationException: The field 'State' contains the value 'Active'
>   that is not in the list of supported values

I use two methods to create a workitem (userstory), to add several workitems (tasks) to this userstory and the second method to link them.

```
// create work item. Used for both Userstory and Task.

static WorkItem CreateWorkItem(string ProjectName, string WorkItemTypeName, Dictionary<string, object> Fields)
        {
            JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

            foreach (var key in Fields.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{key} - {Fields[key]}");
                patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,

                    Path = "/fields/" + key,

                    Value = Fields[key]
                });
            }                

            return WorkItemClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, ProjectName, WorkItemTypeName).Result; // <==FAILS WITH ABOVE ERROR MESSAGE, after the first childitem. The parent item goes fine.
        }
```

// Link user story and child items.

```
static WorkItem LinkChildItems(int ParentWorkItemID, string ChildWorkItemUrl)
{
    JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

    patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Operation.Add,

        Path = "/relations/-",

        Value = new
        {
            rel = "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",

            url = ChildWorkItemUrl,

            attributes = new
            {
                comment = "Automatically added using ADO API."
            }
        }
    });
    return WorkItemClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, ParentWorkItemID).Result;
}
```

Both methods are used in a for loop:

```
// Create new parent item with params projectName, WorkItemType (here: US) and the fields of the dictionary.
var parentItem = CreateWorkItem(teamProject, "User Story", fields);

int parentItemID = parentItem.Id.GetValueOrDefault();

// Counter
int i = 1;
// Loop to create childitems.
foreach (string activity in activityList)
{
     fields["System.Title"] = $"{i}) {activity}: {WorkItemTitle}";               
     var childItem = CreateWorkItem(teamProject, "Task", fields);
     var linkChildToParent = LinkChildItems(parentItemID, childItem.Url);
     i++;
}
```

fields is a Dictionary

```
string WorkItemTitle = "New API used for bulk import";
Dictionary<string, object> fields = new Dictionary<string, object>();
fields.Add("System.Title", WorkItemTitle);
fields.Add("System.Description", $"Automatically created at {DateTime.Now}.");
fields.Add("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority", 4);
fields.Add("System.AssignedTo", "Some Person");
fields.Add("System.State", "Active"); //<--SETS THE STATE ATTRIBUTE
```

If the `System.State` field is removed, the Userstory with child items (the Tasks) is created with no problem. The accepted values for `System.State` should include `Active`, `Closed`, `New` and `Resolved`. 
If I just create one single item with `System.State` set to "`Active`", it also works. It is just when the loop is used on multiple items that my code fails. Anyone has any ideas why this is?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When you create a new work item, the state will have the first value `New`. So, in this case you have to define fields without `System.State`.

   ```
   string WorkItemTitle = "New API used for bulk import";
   Dictionary<string, object> fields = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   fields.Add("System.Title", WorkItemTitle);
   fields.Add("System.Description", $"Automatically created at {DateTime.Now}.");
   fields.Add("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority", 4);
   fields.Add("System.AssignedTo", "Some Person");
   ```

and use `WorkItemClient.CreateWorkItemAsync`

2. Then update `System.State` to `Active`

   ```
   Dictionary<string, object> fields = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   fields.Add("System.State", "Active");
   ```

and use `WorkItemClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync` with your new work item id

Comment: FYI: This applies to any use of the API such as PowerAutomate to create a new item on email received. A second action to `Update a work item` is needed to set the desired state, and you can set it to a custom state. (and thank you, it's now working)